# Как вывести значение из двух массивов в объекте в таблицу?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не совсем получается сделать таблицу исходя из повторяющих значений. Это расписание и там необходимы 3 тега `td`. Но пока не получается, чтобы выходило примерно такой результат

```
9:00
9:15
9:30
9:45
10:00
10:15
и тд
```

Вот в онлайн редакторе https://codepen.io/rusline/pen/NyBYVY?editors=0011

```js
const time = {
  hour: ['9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21'],
  minutes: ['00', '15', '30', '45']
}
function TimeLesson(){
  return(
    <tbody>
      {time.hour.map((hour) => {
          time.minutes.map((minutes) => {
            <tr>
              <th scope='row'>{hour}:{minutes}</th>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          })
        }
      )}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const time = {
  hour: ['9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21'],
  minutes: ['00', '15', '30', '45']
}

var table = document.createElement("table");
for (var i = 0; i < time.hour.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < time.minutes.length; j++) {
    //console.log(time.hour[i]+":"+time.minutes[j]);
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var tdh = document.createElement("td");
    var tdtz = document.createElement("td");
    var tdm = document.createElement("td");
    tdh.innerHTML = time.hour[i];
    tdtz.innerHTML = ":";
    tdm.innerHTML = time.minutes[j];
    tr.appendChild(tdh);
    tr.appendChild(tdtz);
    tr.appendChild(tdm);
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Такой вопрос, а этот идеальный варант для react? или не совсем?

Comment: @Руслан он сделал на ваниле) зачем подключил реакт - хз)

Comment: реактом не пользовался, так-что не знаю

Comment: я просто копировал ))

Comment: Потому что у меня фронтенд на react работает, а этот редактор отрисовать компоненты